# Dim(V) >= Nullity(T)

Tags: linear-algebra

If $T:V \to W$ is a linear transformation the $nullity(T) \le \dim(V)$

I'd like to say its true but I need a proof to show it.

Just not sure where to start. I think whats throwing me off is the prospect that $nullity(T) = dim(V)$

Comment: Well, the nullity can't be greater, can it? And can it attain equality? (No and yes. Why?)

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem

Comment: It can't be greater by the dimension theorem; Rank(T)+Nullity(T) = n. IT could be equal if V is already zero-space then nullity(T)=dim(V)=0?

Comment: If $T(v) = 0$ for all vectors $v \in V$, then $\operatorname{nullity}(T) = \dim(V)$.

Comment: If $T$ is the zero operator then the kernel of $T$ is $V$, so in that case you would have $\mathrm{nullity}(T) = \dim V$.

Comment: so my answer would be. IF T is not the zero operator/transformation then by the dimension theorem rank(T)+nullity(T)=n=dim(V) and if T is the zero operator/transformation then T(v) = 0 for all v $\in$ V thus nullity(T)=dim(V)